# Overpass QL for multiple values without union?

Tags: overpass-api

When querying a parameter and one wants one of multiple values, is there a way to do it with an or statement?

I've found that the union statement works (as below)

```
(
  rel({{bbox}})[route="road"];
  rel({{bbox}})[route="bicycle"];
);
```

But this would seem quite inefficient when I have more values in the future. I was hoping the vertical line operator would do the trick but it doesn't seem to be.

```
(
  rel({{bbox}})[route="road|bicycle"];
);
```

Any way to do this in one query without the union?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A value match by [regular expression](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Value_matches_regular_expression_(%7E,_!%7E)) can be used to achieve this without multiple statements in a union:

```
 rel({{bbox}})[route~"^(road|bicycle)$"];
```